# Laravel - Call Crypt::decrypt() in blade template

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5, datatables

i'm using datatables serverside to get all the data from 2 tables and display them. One of the values that i get is encrypted in the database.

Is there any way to decrypt this value within the blade template before displaying it?

I'm editing other values of the tables using

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full) {}
```

Tried to use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decrypt($value)` but it has no result.

Comment: does there any errors?

Comment: no. Now i tried to just decrypt a random value and display it in the template and it works. Maybe it is the way that i wrote the code?

Comment: 'Maybe it is the way that you encrypt your data'

Comment: i use this code return "<?php Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decrypt('+full[5]+') ?>";  where full[5] is the encrypted value

Comment: why you don't decrypt the data from your server side then send it to your client side

Comment: @dip How was the data encrypted? There are almost infinitely many combinations of encryption. You would need to be specific. Please [edit] your question to expand on that.

Comment: it is a complicated sql query that it runs on routes/web.php How can i decrypt as soon as it directly sends the user to the page

Comment: @dip post your route from `web.php`, please.

Comment: @ArtjomB.The encryption and decryption works fine. The issue is that i don't know how to decrypt in blade within the aocolumns/mrender function

Comment: @IvankaTodorova     Route::get('/serverSideSymv', [
        'as'   => 'serverSideSymv',
        'uses' => function () {
            $symv = App\Symvolaia::Select('table1.*')
                ->join('table2', 'table1.insurancecompanyid', '=', 'table2.id')
                ->join('table3', 'table1.simvalomenos', '=', 'table3.kodikos_pelati')
                ->select('filed1,field2,field3,......');
            return Datatables::of($symv)->make();      THIS IS A PART OF THE SQL QUERY

Comment: @dip Ok, so you are using Laravel Datatables. You can check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`full[5]` is a javascript variable, if you pass it to `Crypt::decrypt()` it will not know it is a javascript variable, but a php constant, because it is inside `<?php ?>`.

You need to "rebuild" your data the way you want it to be displayed in datatables.

To do so, use [`editColumn` method](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/add-edit-remove-column):

```
Route::get('/serverSideSymv', ['as' => 'serverSideSymv', 'uses' => function () {
    $symv = App\Symvolaia::Select('table1.*')->join('table2', 'table1.insurancecompanyid', '=', 'table2.id')->join('table3', 'table1.simvalomenos', '=', 'table3.kodikos_pelati')->select('filed1,field2,field3,......');
    return Datatables::of($symv)
    ->editColumn('your_column', function($data) {
        return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decrypt($data->your_column);
    })
    ->make();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution as below.

```
{{ \Crypt::decrypt($var) }}
```

You can use only `decrypt` function too

```
{{ decrypt($var) }}
```